# Why is my function printing an extra list as the output?

Tags: python, list, function, file

I'm writing a function that reads a .txt file and returns a list of the N most common words. The code I have works, however, along with the list of longestWords, it also prints out a list of all the words in the file before that, and I'm not sure why. If anyone can point me to which line or lines is causing this, it'd be much appreciated. The code is as follows:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as myFile:
    fileText = myFile.read().splitlines()


listOfLines = []
listOfWords = []

for lineNum in range(len(fileText)):
    listOfLines.append(fileText[lineNum].split())

for line in listOfLines:
    for word in line:
        for c in string.punctuation:
            word = word.replace(c, "")
        listOfWords.append(word)

uniqueWords = []

for word in listOfWords:
    if word not in uniqueWords:
        uniqueWords.append(word)

if N > len(uniqueWords):
    print("[Error] The", filename, "contains", len(uniqueWords), "unique words (you asked for ", N, ").")
    return None
else:
    longestWords = []
    wordValPairs = [ [freq, word] for word, freq in wordFrequency(filename).items()]
    wordValPairs.sort()
    for i in range(N):
        longestWords.append(wordValPairs[-1][1])
        wordValPairs.pop()

    return longestWords
```

The file I am using to test this has the following text:

hello hello hello world world!
My My My My My name is Chris Chris Chris Chris Chris Chris Chris

Calling the function returns:

['hello', 'hello', 'hello', 'world', 'world', 'My', 'My', 'My', 'My', 'My', 'name', 'is', 'Chris', 'Chris', 'Chris', 'Chris', 'Chris', 'Chris', 'Chris']
['Chris', 'My']

I only want the second list to return.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code here doesn't seem to produce an extra value, which suggests that it's probably being produced by the caller code or an extra `print` statement that isn't here. Show us the full code!

Comment: After reading your comment, I found that there was in fact an extra print statement within the caller code. Don't know how that slipped by me haha thank you!!!